# when joining two sales tables: Unknown column 'sales_flat_order_item.order_id' in 'on clause'

Tags: magento-1.9, database

I am using this query

```
select product_id, customer_id
from cp8_sales_flat_order
left join cp8_sales_flat_order_item
on sales_flat_order_item.order_id = sales_flat_oder.entity_id
```

but I am getting this error.

```
Unknown column 'sales_flat_order_item.order_id' in 'on clause'
```

and if I swap the order of the last line, then it is entity_id column that is not known.
but can't see why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting error with your query because there is no `sales_flat_order_item` table available, the correct table name is `cp8_sales_flat_order_item` due to the prefix for your table names.

Try using below

```
select sales_flat_order_item.product_id, sales_flat_order.customer_id
from cp8_sales_flat_order AS sales_flat_order
left join cp8_sales_flat_order_item AS sales_flat_order_item
on sales_flat_order_item.order_id = sales_flat_order.entity_id;
```

Comment: thank you, it was the reason I need to wait 5 minutes before I can approve it. Why am I getting all customer_id as NULL? I can clearly see they are not null when looking into the flat_order table.

Comment: use updated code, you require to define from which table you want to get which column.

Comment: Thank you. Hindi people are the saviors of the coders in the world.  धन्यवाद